# How to print loop(?) with commas in Python Listbox?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, tkinter

this is for my assignment
Our teacher hasn't exactly explained it

I wanted to print the loop into a listbox

I followed the code our teacher gave to us, but it was just to create the listbox. Nothing about the loop itself.I wanted to try following the example output he had, but it was just a picture.

I wanted the listbox to show up like this:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5
```

**Code i used:**

```
from tkinter import*
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x250")
listbox = Listbox(root)
listbox.pack(side = LEFT, fill = BOTH)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = BOTH)

for values in range(6):
    print(values, end = ",")
    listbox.insert(END, values)


listbox.config(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command = listbox.yview)

root.mainloop()
```

When I added the 'end = ","', it printed fine in the IDLE Shell but in the actual listbox, it showed up like this:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate the values together into a string and then insert that string into the listbox.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x250")

listbox = Listbox(root)
listbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)

values_str = ""
for value in range(6):
    values_str += str(value) + ","
listbox.insert(END, values_str[:-1])

listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi @Shu if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import*
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x250")
listbox = Listbox(root)
listbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)

listbox.insert(1, ['0,', '1,', '2,', '3,', '4,', '5'])
listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

While Alon Alush answer is correct, I would argue that the pythonic way to do that is using [List Comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) :

```
values = [str(number) for number in range(6)]
item = ', '.join(values)
listbox.insert(END, item)
```